# In the process of moment of inertia calculation

Tags: rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

In calculation of moment of Inertia of a spherical shell, it is required to calculate dA of the small shell.
[image: A spherical shell]

Equation of dA is: $dA=2\pi (Rd\theta)$

I'm confused with $d\theta$. When it is multiplied by R, I think it gives dx as if the shell is  considered as rectangle. How R.dθ gives that dx ?

Comment: $Rd\theta$ is the distance tangent to the sphere and not along the axis. This is what you need here. Otherwise it will be a cylinder and not a sphere.

Comment: The diagram does not show the angle $\theta$.

Comment: θ is the angle made by R with the axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a circle, the radius times the angle swept in radians gives you the arc length.

Here we're considering a really small angle sweep, ${\rm d}\theta$, across the surface of your sphere of radius $R$.  The quantity $R{\rm d}\theta$ is therefore an infinitesimal length across the sphere, which is ${\rm d}x$.